# what to use when we have multiple filter in mongoose function

Tags: javascript, mongoose

```
dbo.collection("collectionName").findOneAndReplace({filter,filter,filter},replace);
dbo.collection("collectionName").findOneAndReplace({key : value, key : value, key : value},replace);
```

when I try to do this

```
throw new TypeError('Replacement document must not contain atomic operators');
```

I have many keyvalue-pairs in my schema and want to filter many keyvalue-pairs. how do I do that using mongoose?

Comment: It only allows one filter.
you should try to combine your all filter condition in one single variable and just pass that.

Comment: better if you provide how you make condition variable for use!